# Android, Room fail on unit testing with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-room, robolectric

I am trying to create some tests for a view model.

The view model includes a Database instantiation which calls a Database

`CallRoomDatabase db = CallRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);`

where getDatabase takes an instance of the Dao()

```
  @Database(entities = {CallEntity.class}, version = 1)
 public abstract class CallRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract CDao cDao();

// marking the instance as volatile to ensure atomic access to the variable
private static volatile CRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

public static CRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (CallRoomDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        CRoomDatabase.class, "database")
                        // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating if no Migration object.
                        // Migration is not part of this codelab.
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

However, when trying to instantiate the model within a test, I get an error on `.build()` above

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:79)
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:952)
at com.s.o.dbutils.CRoomDatabase.getDatabase(CRoomDatabase.java:32)
at com.s.o.viewmodels.CViewModelTest.checkForNuTest(CViewModelTest.kt:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

At `RoomDatabase.java`

```
            T db = Room.getGeneratedImplementation(mDatabaseClass, DB_IMPL_SUFFIX);
```

At `Room.java`  `klass` is `null`

```
        static <T, C> T getGeneratedImplementation(Class<C> klass, String suffix) {
```

I have tried not using the model at all at the test, just instantiate the db with

```
          val db = CRoomDatabase.getDatabase(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
```

Still breaks at the same `.build()`

Any ideas how to get past that exception ?

We dont actually need to test the db someway, just some functions included in that model, so some way to just avoid the error would suffice.

Comment: I faced the same problem now. I guess, your database package does not loaded to `MockClassLoader`. Interestingly, when you define a member variable(`lateinit val db: CallRoomDatabase` ) to your Test class, then there's no error even the variable does not assigned any object.

Answer (score 4):

Room should be tested as an [Android Instrumentation Test](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db#java), not a JUnit test.

**Update:**

Use [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) to mock the database and any repositories.

Utilise mockito methods like:

- *@Mock* - Mocking annotation to mock global and local variables.
- *mock* - Initiate a mock of a class in-line.
- *when* - configure return behavior for mock.
- *verify* - Assert interactions on mocks and their methods.
- *times* - Used with verify to assert number of calls to a mock and it's method.
- *any* - An argument matcher for asserting provided values to mocks.

Using Mockito, example. I don't know how your code works, i made some assumptions like the existence of a Call.class and what mocks you would require:

```
@Mock private CallRoomDatabase database;
@Mock private CRoomDatabase cRoomDatabase;
@Mock private CDao cDao;

private MyClass myClass;

@Before 
public void setUp() {
    // initiate all globally defined mocks annotated with @Mock
    initMocks(this);

    // Setup our expected behaviour from the mock
    when(database.getDatabase()).thenReturn(cRoomDatabase);
    myClass = new myClass(database, cDao);
}

@Test 
public void givenSomeTest_whenCallingGetCall_thenInsertNewCall() {
    // Setup our expected behaviour from the mock
    when(cDao.getCall()).thenReturn(mock(Call.class));

    // do test

    // assert mock interaction with arguments and number of expected calls
    verify(cDao, times(1)).insertCall(any(mock(Call.class)))
}
```

Comment: i dont want to test Room, i want to overcome it.

Comment: Very well, you can use Mockto as a mocking framework to stub the database and return specified values. Updated my answer.

Comment: could you update your answer with an example on how to use mockito to mock the database ?

Comment: Added some example and explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the update.
Using shadow to the RoomDatabase ? what do you think of that ?

Comment: I don't know what Shadow is. If you need any more help with mockito there is an abundance of examples online so hope this helps you get started. Enjoy!

Comment: Room should work in a local JUnit test as [outlined here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pKyOklYCHGW5uthg6ZHzBCPGSzjv7cJeBjRCfn5Eqt8?rm=minimal#bookmark=id.z5yykzqi5msd). The Context can be created using Robolectric in order to create the Database and DAO.

Answer (score 0):

To test the program in isolation from the database, I recommend implementing 2 repositories: 1 repository for the project, 1 for testing and a common interface for them. You can implement this using Dagger 2.

Comment: Do you have any good documentation or samples to provide for this strategy @Destroyer? A quick alternative is also to mock the Repository with MockK or Mockito as done the unit tests for [Coinverse](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse)?